# Upload file from AngularJs to C# Web API as a Body

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, ng-file-upload, steam-web-api

I'm having a Angular Application, in that I'm browsing a file (For example: an XML file) and I'm sending the same with some information like `'Username':'bala'`.

```html
<html>
   
   <head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body ng-app = "myApp">
 
      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
      </div>
      
      <script>
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
         
         myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var modelSetter = model.assign;
                  
                  element.bind('change', function(){
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                     });
                  });
               }
            };
         }]);
      
        myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);

            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {"Content-Type": undefined,}
            })

            .success(function(){
            })

            .error(function(){
            });
        },
        this.uploadFileToUrlasBody = function(file, uploadUrl){
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);

            $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: uploadUrl,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: {
                username:'ram',
                file: file
            },
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    formData.append(key, value);
                });

                var headers = headersGetter();
                delete headers['Content-Type'];

                return formData;
            }
        })

            .success(function(){
            })

            .error(function(){
            });
        }
        }]);
      
         myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
            $scope.uploadFile = function(){
               var file = $scope.myFile;
               
               console.log('file is ' );
               console.dir(file);
               
               var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:40005//api/Sample/UploadData";
               fileUpload.uploadFileToUrlasBody(file, uploadUrl);
            };

$scope.str2ab = function (data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(json);
            var blob = new Blob(data);
    return blob;
    }

         }]);
   
      </script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

My C# Web API has the Controller method with following signature

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadData(SomeModel model) {
    // Main Logic
}

public class SomeModel {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public dynamic file { get; set; } //<-- Wonder if this is right way ?
}
```

HTTP Post Request is not hitting this controller method.

I got the following Request Header

```
Host: localhost:40005
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 381
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------117853232617487
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

Request Body:

```
-----------------------------117853232617487
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

ram
-----------------------------117853232617487
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Client.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Root><TimeOut>00:15:00</TimeOut></Root>
-----------------------------117853232617487--
```

Finally its returning the HTTP Status Code `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Kindly assist me how to send the file in Body as an object (it may be a byte array or stream)

> Note: Don't send the file as a String and I need to send the file in
>   BODY

My Required Signature is

```
public class SomeModel {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public dynamic file { get; set; } //<-- Wonder if this is right way ?
}
```

Comment: Other than the "saving to SQL" part, I think the above question should help you out.

Comment: [Passing file object to Web API from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752036/passing-file-object-to-web-api-from-javascript/33756702#33756702)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I need to send the file in Body not in Header.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - I know to solution to send the file in header, but I need to send the file in BODY. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635108/upload-a-file-using-http-post-and-read-the-request-as-a-filestream-of-c-sharp-we

Comment: @jadarnel27 - Kindly read the question thoroughly before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  That answer *does* send the file in the body of the HTTP request (as multi part form data).  The default model binder will not bind that multipart data to properties on your model (like `dynamic` or `byte[]`).  It's possible that you could create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#model-binders) to accomplish that goal.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote, you're right that this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @jadarnel27: thanks alot...